# Objective-C coding style - #import or #define at the top of the file

Tags: objective-c

I have a general coding style question for Objective C.

When I have a #define in a file, I put it directly below the #import lines of code and above the @implementation line of code:

```
#import "MyLibrary.h"

#define myConstant 99

@implementation MyClass
```

Is this standard style, or is there a standard style of a place to put the defines?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should always put your `#define`s after any imports. Otherwise you will pollute the imported files with your `#define` values and in extreme cases change how they work.

Comment: +1 imagine `#define title AwesomeSauce` followed by `#import <AppKit/AppKit.h>`. Now every call to `-[NSWindow title]` will be compiled as `-[NSWindow AwesomeSauce]`, which will generate lots of errors. Rule: imports first, defines any point afterwards.

Comment: @DaveDeLong: Even if the define was after the import of AppKit, you would still have the same problem in your own code.

Answer (score 2):

Objective-C doesn't really use defines to define constants.

However it is possible to do as you do because Objective-C is backwards compatible with C.

This is how I would do it in Objective-C, in the header file:

```
extern int const MyConstant;
```

In the implementation file:

```
int const MyConstant = 99;
```

Comment: Interesting, but using a #define seems a little easier, is there any reason not to use it?

Comment: No there is no reason to not use it. It is even more convenient some times as the precompiler replaces all the references.

Comment: For more advice along similar lines check out the [Apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingIvarsAndTypes.html). `extern const` for float's/unrelated ints and `enum`'s for related ints

Comment: It's more convient to not use #define as you get auto complete in xcode. Also if you use typedef enum's for integer constants you can pass them to methods and restrict the values to those in the enum

Answer (score 1):

I've never seen any standard on this. `#define`s are almost always at the top of the file (after `#import`s), but the location doesn't much matter.

Comment: See comments on Gil's answer... #define before #import can be a *huge* problem.